# Retrofit API call receives "HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled"

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp, rx-android

Can't figure out why is this happening. Neither one of rx callbacks (onCompleted(), onError(), onNext()) not gets triggered by my call. The only thing i receive is this okhttp output:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json=true&date=20.11.2016 http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
```

Retrofit module:

```
@Module
public class RestModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public HttpLoggingInterceptor providesHttpLogginInterceptor() {
        return new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient providesOkHttpClient(@NonNull HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(ConstantsManager.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(ConstantsManager.READ_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Gson providesGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit providesRetrofit(@NonNull OkHttpClient okHttpClient, @NonNull Gson gson) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ConstantsManager.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public PrivatbankApi providesPrivatbankApi(@NonNull Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(PrivatbankApi.class);
    }
}
```

API interface:

```
public interface PrivatbankApi {

    @GET
    Observable<CurrentRates> loadCurrentRates(@NonNull @Url String url);

    @GET("exchange_rates")
    Observable<DateRates> loadDateRates(@NonNull @Query("json") Boolean json, @NonNull @Query("date") String date);

}
```

Subscription:

```
subscription = dataManager.loadDateRates(date)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doAfterTerminate(() -> {
                })
                .subscribe(dateRates -> {
                    // My code here...
                }, throwable -> {
                    Timber.e(throwable, "Error while loading data occurred!");
                });
```

By the way, both of the calls gets the same error:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://privat24.privatbank.ua/p24/accountorder?oper=prp&PUREXML&apicour&country=ua http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json=true&date=20.11.2016 http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69715645/2914140.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

That exception gets thrown if the request is cancelled by the user. When using `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` this happens if the subscription is unsubscribed before the call can complete. So I guess at some point after you do the call you do `subscription.unsubscribe()` which cancels the underlying requests.

Comment: I have the same problem when it moved to disposable and put it in ondestroy class of the intent service class, and calling `disposable.dispose()`

Comment: Guys, where to do the subscription.unsubscribe() , facing same issue

Comment: I call disposable.dispose() in onDestroy but when Im back to that page after exiting, the `OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled` appeared again. Can someone help me out of this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

What helped to me is to replace deprecated call adapter:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

with:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
```

This helped me with this issue and I get onError() called every time.
More info on this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter

Comment: It saved my day :) thanks
One more example to keep dependencies up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in my case when two requests subscribed in the same `CompositeDisposable` one of them gets cancelled. I mean those 2 requests are done in  parallel.

**My Solution:** I only defined two different subscription channels.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kiskae. This gave me the correct hint. In my case I used a CompositeSubscription and added a subscription to it after it was unsubscribed by another method.

```
/**
 * Adds a new {@link Subscription} to this {@code CompositeSubscription} if the
 * {@code CompositeSubscription} is not yet unsubscribed. If the {@code CompositeSubscription} <em>is</em>
 * unsubscribed, {@code add} will indicate this by explicitly unsubscribing the new {@code Subscription} as
 * well.
 *
 * @param s
 *         the {@link Subscription} to add
 */
```

Comment: Hi, where should i put subscription.unsubscribe() , facing the same issue.

Comment: on the CompositeSubscription which you hold as property / global variable in your class

Comment: remote.getContactDetails(contactId)
                .performOnBackOutOnMain(scheduler)
                .subscribe({
                    data -> mContactResponse.success(data)
                },{
                    error -> mContactResponse.failed(error)
                })
                .addTo(compositeDisposable)

I am giving remote call like this.

Comment: I was actually working with RxJava 1, this seems to be RxJava 2 related. But I guess something unsubscribed from compositeDisposable before you use it

Comment: i am posting my code in few minutes , please have a look once.

Comment: Please check this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739281/http-failed-java-net-socketexception-socket-closed-retrofit?noredirect=1#comment88486176_50739281

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin coroutines I got the same exception. First I closed a `ViewModel` (and a dialog) and then started a `Job` with HTTP-request. In this case the coroutine was cancelled: [kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592144/how-to-fix-kotlin-jobcancellationexception).

```
close()
modelScope.launch {
    val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ...
    }
    response?.let { ... }
}
```

Then I moved closing the `ViewModel` to the end of the request.