# HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

tried with multiple ways still facing this issue as

I am using RxJava and Retrofit to do all my network operations. Below is my code.

> <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

**Service.kt**

```
@GET("/v1/contact/{id}")
fun getContactDetails(@Path("id") id:String): Flowable<ContactDetailResponse>
```

**AccountRepositoryImpl.kt**

```
 override fun contactDetails(contactId:String) {
    mContactResponse.loading(true)
    remote.getContactDetails(contactId)
            .performOnBackOutOnMain(scheduler)
            .subscribe({
                data -> mContactResponse.success(data)
            },{
                error -> mContactResponse.failed(error)
            })
            .addTo(compositeDisposable)
}
```

**Extentions.kt**

```
fun <T> Flowable<T>.performOnBackOutOnMain(scheduler: Scheduler): 
Flowable<T> {
  return this.subscribeOn(scheduler.io())
        .observeOn(scheduler.mainThread())
}
```

**NetworkModule.kt**

```
@Module
class NetworkModule(val key: String, val secret: String) {

 @Provides
 @Singleton
 fun providesRetrofit(jacksonConverterFactory: JacksonConverterFactory,
                     rxJava2CallAdapterFactory: 
 RxJava2CallAdapterFactory,
                     okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
                     baseUrl: String): Retrofit {

    return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(jacksonConverterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
 }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun providesOkHttpClient(cache: Cache, httpInterceptor: 
  HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {

    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(cache)
            .addInterceptor(httpInterceptor)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)


    return client.build()
  }

}
```

Comment: INTERNET permission set in Manifest?

Comment: @Christopher Already given the permission

Comment: Ok, I think we need a more detailed error description. SocketException has several causes. Does the same HTTP request work with a different tool, e.g. Postman? To ensure that the cause is not your backend.

Comment: yes getting response on postman but i issue with this.

Comment: i have also checked this link but not getting where to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823134/retrofit-api-call-receives-http-failed-java-io-ioexception-canceled/46885714?noredirect=1#comment88485479_46885714

Comment: `yes getting response on postman` On your PC? Use a browser on your device.

Comment: Do you by any chance dispose the `compositeDisposable`?

Comment: can you show me your baseUrl ?

Answer (score 1):

You can Create your OkHttp Client like below, I have faced socket closed exception in the low network, after adding following like in OkhttpClient issue resloved

**connectionPool(ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))

protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))**

```
        OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        .connectionPool(ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
        .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
        connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
        }.build()
```